# IOS Emulate Not Respond To Any Click

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, emulation

I'm using ionic when I try to run application to emulator after loading application I can't able to click no response to any click inside the emulator I tried iPhone 6 and 6s and no response, any solution should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your ionic simulator and try following command

```
$ ionic build ios
$ ionic emulate ios

$ cordova prepare ios
```